# iOS: MFMessageComposeViewController for iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to open the SMS message app (MFMessageComposeViewController) in iPad? I already have an app that implements this functionality; tested it in simulator it works good but in iPad, it displays the default error message that it does not support the SMS function. Is there any way to open an SMS app in iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is simple, without Jailbreak there is no way to send SMS from iPad.